# C# AnglesSharp response error "Too Many Requests"

Tags: c#, anglesharp

Я делаю парсер, использую **AnglesSharp** и при попытке получить ресурсы сайта он кидает мне ошибку, мол **слишком много запросов**, хотя в этой тестовой программе я делаю его только один раз при запуске.

Я (в файле HtmlLoader) генерирую ссылку гугла, пример: **https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BC&tbs=qdr:d&start=1&num=100**

После этого делаю к ней запрос:

```
var response = await client.GetAsync(currentUrl);
```

В ответ на что, ловлю ошибку:

[image]

Подскажите, как обойти это или какие есть другие **простые** варианты спарисить эту страничку.

[Ссылка на весь проект (гугл диск)](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/107OkzrOg0ibNKknadNbOaloZn4Y5nARi)

Comment: А что вам не понятно в этом всем? Вам ведь четно написать вашу ошибку "Слишком много запросов", если сайту это не нравиться - ограничивайте, делайте паузы перед повторным.

Comment: Попробуйте прикинуться каким-нибудь браузером. Нужно слать те же хедеры, которые шлют браузеры.